# UILabel created programmatically - find it again?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uilabel

In viewDidLoad I have created 26 UILabels programmatically (one for each letter in the alphabet) and I have put the letters from the alphabet into each label (A in the first, B in the second...).

Later I would like to find one specific label (say, the label containing the letter "F"). I know both the letter I want to find and its index in the alphabet (so for F, I know that its index is 5 because F is the 6th letter in the alphabet)

How can I find this label?

Of course, I can make 26 IBOutlets and refer to them but this seems such a hassle.

This is how I create the labels:

```
// set letters
letters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];

int positionX = 0;
int positionY = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [letters count]; i++) {
    /* a lot of positioning stuff is here (positionX and positionY is set. I have removed this to make the code look cleaner */ 

    UILabel *letterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(positionX, positionY, 50, 50)];
    letterLabel.text = [letters objectAtIndex:i];
    letterLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    letterLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:45];
    letterLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:letterLabel];
    [letterLabel release];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two basic ways to do this:

#### 1. Create An Array

Simply make an `NSMutableArray` as an ivar in your view controller, then add the labels as they’re created. To find F, use `[myArray objectAtIndex:5]`.

#### 2. Use Tags

When you create the label, set its tag (`[letterLabel setTag:i]`). Then, when you want to retrieve it, use `[[self view] viewWithTag:5]`.

Comment: oh, damn... 1 second difference.

Comment: Re creating an array... you've already got one: `[self.view subviews]`. Your elements will always be in the same position in there, so you may as well index into that. That said, for this particular need, I'd use tags.

Comment: @Dan Ray: True, but who knows what other subviews will be in there.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, but they'll always be in the order they were added, and it'd be unlikely you'd be surprised by anything in there. There may be things in the array before your fields start, but it's simple enough to step over those. It's not ideal, but I hate to make a second structure just to hold what I've already got somewhere else. That said: tags. Simpler, better, easier to map to the index of letters.

Comment: Great idea with the tags! But when doing so, I get the error that "'UIView' may not respond to 'setTextColor:'" As you can see, I would like to change the color of the label but it is regarded a view. Is there anyway to "convert" this UIView to a UILabel?

Comment: @SimonBS: Make sure that you cast your view: `UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[[self view] viewWithTag:i];`

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches I can think of:

1. Add all your labels to an `NSArray`;
2. Set the `tag` property for all the labels with a specific know value for each label and access them with `[self.view viewWithTag:TheTagForTheLabel];`

Comment: Good idea with the tags. I should have thought about that. When trying to set the textColor of the UILabel I get the warning, that "UIView may not respond to setTextColor". It work though but is there a way to convert this UIView to a UILabel?

Comment: Yeah, you can just cast the pointer like `UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagValue];`

Answer (score 1):

I probably would've created an NSMutableDictionary with an NSString containing the letter as the key and the associated UILabel as the object.